# Material UI DataTable sort order not working

Tags: sorting, datatable, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am using material UI DataTable 3.2.0 to load data and the code as follows. I have enabled sort:true for all the columns. But sorting won't work when I click on the column name.

```
<MUIDataTable
    data={this.state.data}
    columns={this.state.columns}
    options={{
        pagination: true,
        serverSide: true,
        sort: true,
        count: this.state.totalItems,
        rowsPerPage: 20,
        page: this.state.filterData.page,
        sortOrder: this.state.sortOrder,
        onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
            console.log(action, tableState)
            switch (action) {
                case 'changePage':
                    this.setPage(
                        tableState.page
                    )
                    break
                case 'sort':
                    this.setState({
                        sortOrder: tableState.sortOrder
                    });
                    break
```

Note: I have tried assigning value manually to the sortOrder as,

```
sortOrder: {
  "name": "to",
  "direction": "asc"
}
```

even this won't work.